# hadoop streaming python windows cannot run mapreduce subprocess failed with code 64

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm trying to run a simple mapreduce word-count program with python on Windows and I got this error:

```
2021-08-07 23:30:14,670 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
attempt_1628353447352_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 64
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2021-08-07 23:30:15,063 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
attempt_1628353447352_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 64
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2021-08-07 23:30:23,210 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
attempt_1628353447352_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 64
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2021-08-07 23:30:23,216 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
attempt_1628353447352_0001_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 64
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2021-08-07 23:30:31,358 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
attempt_1628353447352_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 64
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

2021-08-07 23:30:32,379 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
attempt_1628353447352_0001_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 64
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
```

Here is the command which I used:

```
yarn jar C:\hadoop-3.2.2\share\hadoop\tools\lib\hadoop-streaming-3.2.2.jar -input /input -output /output2 -mapper "python D:\mapper.py" -reducer "python D:\reducer.py"
```

I used Hadoop 3.2.2 and the python script is from [this site](https://xiaohan.me/2016/01/17/MapReduce-Run-Word-Count-with-Python-and-Hadoop/). I tried to google but couldn't find the solution. Hope someone could show me how to solve this problem or any relevant post

Comment: I suggest using `mrjob` library, not hadoop-streaming

Comment: @OneCricketeer, `mrjob` library uses hadoop-streaming.jar, right? So I think I will get the same problem.

Comment: Not necessarily. It can also run Spark jobs or run without Hadoop. In any case, the YARN UI might give you more details about the error since `exit code 64` is not very descriptive. For example, maybe `D:` drive cannot be read by your hadoop user